# what are the disadvantages laptop using without battery

Tags: power-supply

i use my lappy without battery.it means i remove the battery and laptop cable join the direct current supply.but laptop is working.can i know through this what happen to my laptop.is it good or bad to my laptop?THANKS.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: Now this may just be bad luck but last week I plugged the charger into my Dell XPS laptop forgetting that I had removed the battery. I was met with an "HDD failure" error message. Windows Repair was unable to fix the problem but fortunately the BIOS diagnostics & repair utility did. I won't do it again.

Answer (score 4):

While this is not an electronic design question AS ASKED it has implications for designs using Lithium Ion (LiIon) batteries.

As you know, turning off the power will immediately stop the laptop.

BUT leaving the battery unused can be good for it compared to subjecting it to charge discharge cycles unnecessarily as long as it is stored in a "good" state.

The best state to leave the battery in is when it has finished constant current charging and has just started constant voltage charging.   This occurs in the 40 to 50 minute range when charging from fully discharged with most LiIon batteries.

Storing fully charged is better than storing empty.